# How can I identify where a thread is touching another thread's stack?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I'm running an application through Intel's Inspector XE, and it's telling me that one of my threads is accessing another thread's stack, but it can't tell me which threads are involved or where in the code it's happening.

I was thinking there might be some sort of per-thread `VirtualProtect` or some way to have code called during context switches, but I can't find anything.

Is there any way for me to catch the threads in the act, or am I out of luck?

Comment: I expect this is possible if you were to pass a pointer to a local variable into another thread.  Do you do that?  Is it actually a problem?

Comment: This is a 100k+ line and heavily threaded application, anything is possible.

Comment: When your application is in a state where "anything is possible", then you are lost. Then the application is a lost game. Otherwise: analyse the code and find out where one thread passes a pointer (or reference) to a stack variable to another thread. There might have been a reason to do so, and that reason might lead to a better insight.

Answer (score 0):

Start at the thread creation routines. Make sure the pointer passed doesn't point into the stack. You ought to be able to use grep to help with this. eg. Assuming you use pthreads, `grep -E pthread_create\([^,]+\,[^,]+\,[^,]+\,[^&]+\& *.c` or something similar might give you the culprits, if the pointer is made using the & operator in a pthread_create function call.

You might consider building a list of array identifiers, using `grep -E "[[:alnum:]_]+[[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]_]+\[[^]]+]" *.c`, and building a list of patterns based on any arrays declared inside functions.

Otherwise, `grep -E pthread_create *.c` would at least give you each line that creates a thread, and the expression for the pointer that's passed to the entrance point. If that pointer points to a malloc'd struct or pointer (eg. `fubar **argument; argument = malloc(sizeof *argument);`), find where that struct or pointer is modified and make sure it's not modified to point into the stack.